# How is $\tau = \{\varnothing, \{a\},\{b\},\{c\},X \}$ a topology on $X = \{a,b,c\}$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

> How is $\tau = \{\varnothing, \{a\},\{b\},\{c\},X
> \}$ a topology on $X = \{a,b,c\}$ ?

So if I consider the union of $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ I get $\{a,b\}$ but that doesn't belong to $\tau$. So am I correct to say that the given $\tau$ is not a topology on $X$ ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, $t$ is not a topology.

Comment: Correct, if you could explain where you got the idea that it was a topology, we might be better able to explain what went wrong

Comment: It is a base for a topology, the discrete topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Correct ! $\tau$ is not a topology

Note that, the only topology on $X$ in which singletons are open is the discrete topology!